# How to solve error in Angular Firebase Authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angularfire

According to several guides I setup Angular Firebase Auth (added Google, Facebook, Anonymous)

```
import { GoogleAuthProvider, FacebookAuthProvider, GithubAuthProvider, OAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth'
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth'
```

```
readonly angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth = inject(AngularFireAuth)
```

```
loginWithGoogle(): Promise<ProviderUserCredential> {
  return this.angularFireAuth.signInWithPopup(new GoogleAuthProvider())
}
```

```
"@angular/fire": "^16.0.0",
```

and try to login as a user having following error in console 4 times in a row when I open pop-up:

**main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.**

Then, an extra error in console after applying any user.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: (0 , m.__rest) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , m.__rest) is not a function
    at new oe (main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:28842)
    at main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:33125
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at r (main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:2177436)
    at ne (main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:2177646)
    at main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:2177710
    at new t (polyfills.27a67f4029681117.js:1:18388)
    at main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:2177585
    at oe._fromIdTokenResponse (main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:33212)
    at main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:69515
    at z (polyfills.27a67f4029681117.js:1:16000)
    at z (polyfills.27a67f4029681117.js:1:15550)
    at polyfills.27a67f4029681117.js:1:16832
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.27a67f4029681117.js:1:7203)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:1269912)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.27a67f4029681117.js:1:7124)
    at L.runTask (polyfills.27a67f4029681117.js:1:2583)
    at _ (polyfills.27a67f4029681117.js:1:9220)
```

**main.b498f38b5156900e.js:1:28842**

```
 var {uid: M, auth: Y, stsTokenManager: we} = b
                  , ct = (0,
                m.__rest)(b, ["uid", "auth", "stsTokenManager"]);
```

But, in the Firebase console **([https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/{name}/authentication/users](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/%7Bname%7D/authentication/users))** the following user is added - it is the list. Like it was added successfully. If I try to login again (with the same user), I have the same error.

When I connect auth like

```
this.angularFireAuth.signInAnonymously()
```

I have the same error without any popup to be opened

I am trying to get a meta-data of a user, like it authId, displayName, etc.
What I am doing wrong?